# iOS13 breaking changes to UISplitviewController, how to fix genericly in Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, ios13

I have a legacy application that uses a UISplitViewController for a master/detail view. This behaves differently on iOS up to 12 vs. 13. For instance if you start an appin landscape it will show both master and detail. Rotate left and it will only display detail. Rotate right (to original landscape orientation) and still only detail is shown. This even works differently on iPad Pro vs iPad 7th generation vs iPad Air 2.

(This behaviour is also explained in http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4969975819272192)

```
class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
}

func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
        print("Split view controller function")
        guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
        guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
        if topAsDetailController.passedEntry == nil {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I would like to make changes to the default behaviour of UITSplitViewController instances in the app, either in AppDelegate or in a Cordova plugin as a workaround until Apple fixes iOS13. Is anyone else experiencing the same problems? Any suggestion how to do this?